# saving audio file to SD card

Tags: java, android

I have written a program that records audio and saves it to external storage SD card. I can also playback the audio. The audio file is saved according to time stamp. The problem is that when the recording is saved, it is saved with two additional files that are both 0KB and cannot be opened. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the time stamp, but working at it for a while. I'm just a novice programmer so its taking me a while to solve this. If anyone might can give suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It will be hard for anyone to help you without seeing the code which does the recording and likely details of the files themselves.  For example, use `ls -l` on them from the adb shell.

Comment: MediaRecorder.reset();
 time = getTimestamp();
         MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
         MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
         MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
         MediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+time+".3gp");

Comment: @sunil , this is the part where the file is saved so it should be a problem here...i have get time use simpleDateTime format...SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

Comment: use like that new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm"),

Comment: i removed the seconds it but now, the program crashes at random times...also, when i playback the recording the saved file become 0KB

Comment: @sunil..............................